# Organizing rows and columns in css

Tags: jquery, css

I have two rows with 3 columns, but the first two columns in the second row are being pushed down. Why??? :)

Here's my fiddle Just click on "New York" http://jsfiddle.net/q9cfa6qu/13/

```
/* accordion header */
 .accordion  h2 {
     background:#A91414;
     width:250px;
     font-size:18px;
     font-weight:bold;
     cursor:pointer;
     color: #fff;
     margin:15px;
     text-align:center;
     text-transform:uppercase;
     float:left;padding:9px 50px 9px 50px;
  }

 /* accordion header */
.accordion2 h2 {
     background:#000;
}

/* currently active header */
.accordion h2.current {
     cursor:default;
     background-color:#B40404;

}
/* currently active header */
.accordion2 h2.current {
    cursor:default;
    background-color:#000;
}
/* accordion pane */
.accordion .pane {
    display:none;
    padding:15px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:16px;
    float:left;
    width:99%;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Do you mean, why the images of Stop&Shop and Shop Rite are below the adresses of WholeFood?

Comment: See this http://screencast.com/t/3JGeTqx1cj See how the second row is not aligned like the first. In jfiddle you have to extend the screen really wide to see the states in columns and see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your h2 buttons of

```
<h2>Kitchen Kabaret
    409 Glen Cove Rd.
    Roslyn Heights, NY</h2>
```

collidates with the height of the parent shop h2 buttons!
If you look at shop 1 and 2, they are heightier (is that the word :) ?) than the third.
The 15px margins in .accordion h2 let the child h2 float to 3rd position an then continue in the next row.
To fix that, you should set the shop buttons with the images to a fixed height. Probably you should give them a seperate class for that, so that you are not affecting you country h2 buttons.

Comment: take a look to your screenshot. There you have drawn the rectangle just below the Whole Food button and you can see, that there can't be space of 30px in total to the child buttons

Comment: I was thinking this but I never actually did it. I just put width=100 and height=100 in all images in the fiddle just to see and it worked. Thank you!!!